# Adding missing value in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python

I have a dataframe of following structure (showing it as comma separated values):

```
day        date      hour cnt
Friday   9/15/2017    0    3
Friday   9/15/2017    1    5
Friday   9/15/2017    2    8
Friday   9/15/2017    3    6
...........................
Friday   9/15/2017    10
...........................
Saturday 9/16/2017    21   5
Saturday 9/16/2017    22   4
```

Some of the date values have data for every hour (0-23).

However, some of the date values can have missing hours. In the example, for 9/15/2017 data, there are no records for hour values from 9 to 13. For all these missing records, I need to add a new record with a `cnt` value (last column) of zero.

How do I achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you use `pandas.DataFrame` you may use [fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method:

```
 DataFrame['cnt'].fillna(value=0, axis=1)
```

---

#### Example:

Consider `data`:

```
        one     two     three
a       NaN     1.2  -0.355322
c       NaN     3.3   0.983801
e       0.01     4   -0.712964
```

You may fill `NaN` using `fillna()`:

```
data.fillna(0)

        one     two     three
a        0      1.2  -0.355322
c        0      3.3   0.983801
e       0.01     4   -0.712964
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a `DatetimeIndex` and use `resample` method:

```
#suppose your dataframe is named df:
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['date']).add(pd.to_timedelta(df['hour'], unit='h')))
df.index = idx
df_filled = df[['cnt']].resample('1H').sum().fillna(0).astype(int)
df_filled['day'] = df_filled.index.strftime('%A')
df_filled['date'] = df_filled.index.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y')
df_filled['hour'] = df_filled.index.strftime('%-H')
```

or you can do the pivot and unpivot trick:

```
df_filled = df.pivot(values='cnt',index='date',columns='hour').fillna(0).unstack()
df_filled = df_filled.reset_index().sort_values(by=['date','hour'])
```